# How can I get rid of this warping?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, procedural

[image]The mountain landscape here was created in eevee with an 8k rock texture.  There seems to be warping, especially on the right side of the mountain.  How can I get rid of this warping?
I used object texture coordinates to provide the vector for the bump node.
I was trying to blend with a noise texture, but every time I use procedurally generated textures in my bump nodes for normal maps, my rendered view in eevee immediately starts to lag horribly (is there a way around this/setting I need to have to avoid this?  Do I need to specifically tell Blender to run on the gpu?).  I use a gaming pc with an NVIDIA gpu for my Blender projects so I'm not sure why it's lagging so much when I procedurally textures in my bump nodes for normal maps.[image]

Comment: If it's lagging it means that your scene is getting to the point where it is larger than what your computer can handle confortably. 8K images will use a lot of resources.

Comment: Much less lag when using the 8k textures.  Lag occurs when using procedural textures for bump nodes into normal input for BSDF node.

Comment: Show us your node tree.. There's something spherical going on here?

Comment: Updated to show node tree.